# WSPBuilder in Visual Studio 2010 for solution in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: web-part, wspbuilder

I've installed the WSPBuilder extension for Visual Studio 2010 and I'm looking for a walkthrough of how to create a deployment package for my web-part.  Can anyone point me to a good resource?  Everything I find seems to be directed towards VS 2008 and it creates the folder structure differently.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this post if you haven't  https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Dev/Pages/WSPBuilder%20for%20SharePoint%202010%20in%20Visual%20Studio%202010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting as an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment the OP.

I jst wanted to inform you of [CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) in case you don't allready know of it. I have used it in all SP2010 projects so far and I am 100% satisfied with it.